# how to allow exact word match to have higher score

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In elastic search, I have defined two synonyms for "swim", like "play", "walk".

Say if I have only two values in elastic search with value `"I like to swim"`, `"I like to play"`.

If the user enter a query `"I hope to play"` I want it to match "`I like to play"` with a higher score than `"I like to swim"` (exact word matches (in this case `play`) to have higher score), is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can !

You can acheive any boost you want with the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

The global concept and that you will define `must` clauses that need to be matched, and `should` that could match and thus add a boost in your document score.

So for your need, document **needs** to match with synonyms, and **should** match without it.

You just need to index your searchable fields with two properties, one with synonyms and another without synonyms.

and example could be

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text.withSynonyms": "I hope to play"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text.withoutSynonyms": "I hope to play"
          }
        }
      ]

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to defined two fields with two indices without repeating the field data?

Comment: In addition, how to specify the boost in the query?

Comment: did you mean two field with two different analyzer? Yes you can see here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html but of course it will increase your index size, but that the cost for relevance =) And to boost some match query you can use { "match": {
                    "text.withoutSynonyms": {
                        "query": "I hope to play",
                        "boost": 3 
                    }
                }